# Python: Read existing Excel file and select a different dropdown value

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I want to be able to open an xlsx file in Python and select a different dropdown value in a cell which should trigger an update for the entire spreadsheet based on the new value (just how it currently does so if I manually select a different value). How can I do this in Python and which library can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You can't.

In order to get cascading execution, you need to access the Excel execution engine. Python libraries do not have a copy of this.

If you wish to change additional values in the spreadsheet, you will need to write your Python code to make the changes.

*Caveat:* There technically is a way to do it using pywin32 if you have a version of Excel installed. In this case Python is simply feeding instructions to Excel, no differently than if you were using VBA. It is significantly more complicated than changing a value using a library such as Openpyxl.

Comment: I see. That's unfortunate. Maybe a work-around for me could be to change those values, save the spreadsheet and re-load it with the updated values. That might update the spreadsheet as well. I just need to find a way to manipulate dropdowns via openpyxl. Currently just using .value is breaking the sheet because it's removing the dropdown and replacing it with the text value. Any idea on how if i could at least select a different drop down value via openpyxl?

Comment: @dev It's in the [data validation section](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validation.html) - more details [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.html). Essentially you have to do something like set your value and then rebuild the dropdown. Data validation is not well supported in the python libraries.