# How to click on a filter in excel and choose an option using python

Tags: python-3.x, excel

I have an excel file like this one:

[image]

In the A:4 cell, I have a filter with two options: **YES** and **NO**.

How can I open this excel file with python and choose option **YES**?

Comment: Check the comments under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67669494/9245853).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was easier than I thought, I just used openpyxl to write YES in that cell:

```
import openpyxl

path=r'~\test1.xlsx'
workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
worksheet=workbook.active
worksheet['A4'] = 'YES'

workbook.save(path)
workbook.close()
```